# Display confirmation message after avoiding form resubmission?

Tags: php, html

I have created a web page, where after you complete a form, the page is redirected to itself to avoid form resubmission. However, I would like to display a confirmation message after the page is redirected. Below, I have my current code for this. I need the echo statement to show up below the form after the header is ran. I read somewhere that i should append a $_GET parameter to the URL, but I don't know what that means or how to do it as I am a complete newbie to PHP.

```
    <form action="<?php $PHP_SELF ;?>" method="POST">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
        <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"></p>
        <p>Message: </p>
        <p><textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>

        <!-- TO-DO: Add form validations -->

        <!-- Start PHP Code -->
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $from = $_POST['email'];
                $to = "comp@c0mp.org";
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];

                mail($to, $subject, "Name: " . $name . "\nMessage: " . $message, "From:" . $from);

                header('Location: http://c0mp.org');

                echo "Your message has been sent!";
            }
        ?>
        <!-- End PHP Code-->
```

Comment: you can create new page and redirect on that page, ie: create success.php or something and redirect it using header location, same way you are doing

Comment: For additional information, you must not use `header('Location: http://c0mp.org')` after HTML codes. It will show warnings in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to your redirect url:

```
header('Location: http://c0mp.org?status=success');
```

Now you can check for that parameter and display the correct message:

```
if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] === "success"){
    echo "Your message has been sent!";
}
```

**Note:**  Move your POST code on top of the page, you might run into problems where it refuses to redirect because content has already been sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to redirect to another page. You only need an strategy to hiding form elements if it has been submitted.

Take a look at this sample code. You check the sent value. If it has been sent, you will process it and show your message, else you show the form.
You can change it to what you need.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['your_name'])) {
   echo 'Your name is: ' . $_POST['your_name'];
} else {
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
Your name: <input type="text" name="your_name" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

**Notation:** Using `header()` function after HTML codes is incorrect and will shows warnings in your web page.

Answer (score 0):

otherwise, If you just want the server the memory the submission status, just use session.

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST["name"])){
       $_SESSION["submit"] = 1;
    }
    //Very beginning of the file
    ?>
    <!-- ..maybe something else here (html head meta title...) -->


    <?php if(isset($_SESSION["submit"])){ ?>
    <h3>You have already submitted</h3>
    <?php } ?>


    <form action="<?php $PHP_SELF ;?>" method="POST">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"></p>
    <p>Message: </p>
    <p><textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>

    <!-- TO-DO: Add form validations -->

    <!-- Start PHP Code -->
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $to = "comp@c0mp.org";
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            mail($to, $subject, "Name: " . $name . "\nMessage: " . $message, "From:" . $from);

            header('Location: http://c0mp.org');

            echo "Your message has been sent!";
        }
    ?>
    <!-- End PHP Code-->
```

Comment: The only problem is, the echo isn't being sent. it never actually shows up.

Comment: @Compressions  because your redirect header has already been sent. The browser will redirect before display "Your message has been sent!". Use this one:  header("refresh:2;url=http://c0mp.org");